# Two date data differences in datagridview

Tags: c#, database, datagridview, datetimepicker, datagridviewcolumn

How do I get two date data in datagridview and find the difference and print the user information to another gridview?

```
string fark;
fark = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value.ToString();
label3.Text = fark;
```

Comment: I don't get it?!

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to share your problem. But there is something missing from your question that is unclear. What is your goal and your difficulty? What have you done so far? Please try to better explain your issue, your development environment and the data structures, as well as to share more code (no screenshot), some samples, images or sketches of the screen, and user stories or scenario diagrams. To help you improve your requests, please read the *[How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)* and **Questions I avoid asking** at the top right.

Comment: Show how datagridview is populated. Remember that datagridview is just a UI control which displays underlying datasource. DataSource can be a DataTable or collection of some objects. To find difference between some values do this on underlying datasource not UI control.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick sample...

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DataGridViewDate_58659544_
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        BindingList<dgv1item> dgvData = new BindingList<dgv1item>();
        DataGridView dgv1 = new DataGridView();
        DataGridView dgv2 = new DataGridView();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dgv1.Location = new Point(5,5);
            dgvData.Add(new dgv1item(new DateTime(2019, 5, 1), new DateTime(2020, 5, 1)));
            dgv1.DataSource = dgvData;
            Controls.Add(dgv1);

            dgv2.Location = new Point(5, 175);
            dgv2.Columns.Add("datediff", "date difference");
            TimeSpan datedifference = dgvData[0].date2 - dgvData[0].date1;
            dgv2.Rows.Add(datedifference);
            Controls.Add(dgv2);
        }
    }

    class dgv1item
    {
        public DateTime date1 { get; set; }
        public DateTime date2 { get; set; }

        public dgv1item(DateTime Date1, DateTime Date2)
        {
            date1 = Date1;
            date2 = Date2;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but times will be taken from the database " date of_registration "  " end_date "